# Convert Silverlight App to WPF

Tags: wpf, silverlight

I need to convert a Silverlight App to WPF (to finally run it on Microsoft Surface 1.0).

I didn't write the original solution and it is quite big. I've never worked with Silverlight and I'm just a little bit familiar with WPF.

Can you offer some advice on completing this project?

Here's my current plan (high level view):

- Recreate all Silverlight projects in WPF (User Control in Silverlight = WPF User Control Library ?)
- References are not the same so I'll need to make some changes ... I think :)
- Hope all controls are compatible with WPF ...

Have I missed something big? Is something wrong? Incomplete?

I'm open to all your suggestions and advice!

Any development tips ?

Comment: WPF User Control Library ~= Silverlight Class Library.
The larger the app is, the more likely you'll spend considerable time working around differences - but at least most things should be available when going SL->WPF, even if you need to change/debug lots.

Comment: Thank you, step by step i'm learning new stuff :)

Comment: Question: do you intend for the target WPF assembly to be deployed as partial or full trust? As a stand-alone exe, or as an XBAP? These should be taken into account in the very early stages of setting your conversion strategy.

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party controls which would run only on Silverlight

Comment: You can use Silverlight Controls in WPF, but not WPF controls in Silverlight.  You just have to reference the correct DLLs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recently converted a Silverlight app to WPF. You can find my notes on how I did it here:

http://robertsmyth.blogspot.com.au/2011/12/migrating-from-silverlight-to-wpf.html

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

"User Control in Silverlight = WPF User Control Library ?" Not exactly. 
which version of silverlight do you use? Most difficult issue I have faced while porting **WPF to Silverlight** was with converters. Silverlight 4.0 or lower doesn't support Ancestor RelativeSource Binding. But supported in Silverlight 5!

Hope this link will help you. [WPF and Silverlight 2 Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc895632.aspx)